# Can i overwrite the remoteAddress as provided by the Channel in Netty 4?

Tags: proxy, netty

Im implementing a [Proxy Protocol](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) decoder in Netty 4. This protocol allows an external proxy (in this case HAProxy) to provide remote address details to an internal server behind the proxy server.

To include this in my pipeline i need to override the SocketAddress provided by the Netty Channel. I guess i could just put the address provided by Proxy Protocol on the channel as an attribute, but id prefer to keep the decoder non-specific to my application if possible and just update the remoteAddress directly on the channel.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope you can't override it as it is specific to the transport.

Answer (score 0):

As Norman mentioned, it's currently impossible.  However, there's an ongoing discussion on how we have to implement proxy support seamlessly.  Exposing the backend remote address is also one of the questions we have to answer for proper proxy support.  Please feel free to join the discussion: https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/1740

Comment: thanks for the clarification, are there any plans to implement transparent support (without using attributes) down the track? e.g. netty 5.

Comment: The plan is to add such special attributes in 4.x, so people don't need to wait for 5.

Comment: Do you think it's better having more type-safe API such as: `channel.isProxied()? channel.proxyInfo().remoteAddress() : channel.remoteAddress()`?

Comment: my preference would be for the proxied remoteAddress to be updated transparently on the channel

Comment: IIUC, you expect: `channel.remoteAddress()` returns the proxied remote address instead of the address of the proxy server, right?  That's actually my plan.

Comment: yep that would be perfect. it keeps the proxy as a pipeline detail rather than something you need to worry about at a higher level.

Comment: Cool. Please keep in mind you can even make a contribution. :-)

Comment: ha :) yeah i'd love to, unfortunately im still very much a novice when it comes to this stuff...